# Why did textarea auto tab indent?

Tags: php, html, css, textarea

I have a problem when load data from database into textarea tag in PHP + HTML. Specifically, textarea tag auto text indent although I do not set padding attribute in CSS. I do not know why is it like that? Can anyone help me? Thanks so much.

This is my HTML code:

```
<td colspan="2">
              <label for="">mô tả sản phẩm</label>
              <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10">
                <?php echo $p->getColumn("select description from tbl_products where id = '$get_id_update'"); ?>
              </textarea>
            </td>
```

[image]

I have just tried trim() to format string, but it is not work

Comment: Don't use newlines when starting text in a textarea. Start your text right after closing the starting tag. `cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $p->getColumn(...`

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by the whitespace characters  between the `<textarea>` tags and the PHP code.

```
<td colspan="2">
    <label for="">mô tả sản phẩm</label>
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo trim($p->getColumn("select description from tbl_products where id = '$get_id_update'")); ?></textarea>
</td>
```

By removing the whitespace characters, the `<textarea>` element will no longer be indented.

Comment: Amazing ! It's work. I cannot thank you enough.